# Scala, output to multiple files/streams

Tags: scala

I need to write the same text to multiple files (or streams).
Sometimes I need to use Writer, sometimes a PrintWriter, sometimes a OutputStream...

One way to do this in Java wold be to extend a PrintWriter to have an array of PrintWriters and overridde each method as follows:

```
class MutiplePrintWriter extends PrintWriter {
    private PrintWriter[] outs;
    public MutiplePrintWriter(PrintWriter[] outs) { this.out = out; }

    public void print(boolean b) { for (PrintWriter out : outs) print(b); }
    public void print(char c) { for (PrintWriter out : outs) print(c); }
    public void print(char[] s) { for (PrintWriter out : outs) print(s); }
    ...
}
```

(and the same for Writer, OutputStream...)

Is there a better alternative in Scala?

Is this already implemented in a library in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer your question in the java-world: Implement your multi-writer class on `OutputStream` level and then stack a `Writer`/`PrintWriter` on top:

```
class MultiOutputStream(val outs: Array[OutputStream]) extends OutputStream {
  override def close() = {
    super.close()
    outs.foreach(_.close)
  }
  override def flush() = {
    super.flush()
    outs.foreach(_.flush)
  }
  def write(c: Int) = outs.foreach(_.write(c))

  // overridden for efficiency
  override def write(b: Array[Byte], off: Int, len: Int) = 
    outs.foreach(_.write(b,off,len))
}
```

Now create out of this whatever you need:

```
val outs = //...
val out = new PrintStream(new MultiOutputStream(outs))
```

This way, the `PrintStream` takes care of all the formatting business, while you only have to redirect data.